# Создать картинку UIimage/CGimage с заданными размерами

Tags: objective-c, изображения, uiimage

Уважаемые коллеги!

Не получается что-то создать картинку по умолчанию (не получить откуда-то, а именно создать).

Нужно создать объект `UIImage` (можно как вариант `CGImage`)c размерами 288*352 пикселей.

**Вопрос:** как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например так: (создает изображение нужного размера и заливает серым)

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(288, 352));
CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(0,0,288,352);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 100.0f/255.0f, 100.0f/255.0f, 100.0f/255.0f, 1.0f);
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), drawRect);
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); // вот ваше изображение
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Спасибо,  Это то, что мне нужно и то, чего мне таааак не хвааатааало. Ты  очень похож на специалиста судя по ответу. Можно тогда ещё простенький вопрос тебе лично? 
У меня ощущения, что многие команды связанные с обработкой изображения (классы uiimage и cgimageref) жрут много памяти, а экземпляр image (будь то класс UIImage или CGImageRef) не "убить" строкой `image = nil`. Я прав? Как в таком случае правильно уничтожить объект этих классов?

Comment: создайте новый вопрос.